# Can't see `ps --version`

Tags: ps

When I write `ps --version` in the terminal it gives output as `ps from procps-ng UNKNOWN`. Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Ubuntu Version - `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS`

```
$ type -a ps
ps is /bin/ps
$ apt-cache policy procps
procps:
Installed: 2:3.3.16-1ubuntu2.1
Candidate: 2:3.3.16-1ubuntu2.1
Version table:
 *** 2:3.3.16-1ubuntu2.1 500
500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
2:3.3.16-1ubuntu2 500
500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Add the version of Ubuntu, the output of `type -a ps` and `apt-cache policy procps` to your post, please.

Comment: @muru Ok, added the information

Comment: You ask for the version of ps, and that is what the answer is. What did you expect as result ?

Comment: That seems to be the unexpectedly expected output from `ps` on Ubuntu 20.04, testing on a Docker container. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: A bug was reported about this a couple months ago: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/1917148

Comment: Will reinstalling ubuntu again will solve this problem??

Comment: No, it's a bug (that's probably harmless so no one's bothered to do anything about it). I don't think this (the incorrect version reporting) is the cause of your `reniced` problem by itself.

Comment: So what do you think @muru, what is the problem in it? Or do you know a solution for setting a niceness to an app for permanent, so I dont have to change it everytime I open up that application??